# Extracting last row values from spreadsheets with python - Encountering 'NoneType'

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to extract the last row of an Excel spreadsheet:

```
import openpyxl 
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Folder/File.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
last_row = sheet.max_row
```

This returned 44 from `sheet.max_row`. But there are no values in the last few rows of the spreadsheet, they are blank.

`type(sheet['A44'].value)` returns `NoneType`.

I want to extract the values in the last row (Row 37 in this case) and append it in a Pandas data frame. How do I ignore the `NoneType` values in the last rows spreadsheet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search for the last non-empty item in column 'A' with:

```
last_row = sheet.max_row
while sheet.cell(column=1, row=last_row).value is None and last_row > 0:
    last_row -= 1
last_col_a_value = sheet.cell(column=1, row=last_row).value
```